# How to use org-capture template expansion on finish?

Tags: org-mode, org-capture, template

I would like to capture the time when I **finish** an org-capture template with C-c C-c.

Is it possible? And how is it possible to use the given templates (i.e., the template `%U`) for this?

Best
Jonas

Comment: Captures are supposed to be very short: a few seconds in most cases, certainly less than a minute. The idea is to capture an item as quickly as possible so that it does not interrupt the work that you are doing. Refiling it and perhaps adding details, prioritizing, scheduling, and so on, is done later, perhaps on your daily review. Does it really make  any difference *when* you finished the capture? You can probably cook up something with the `:after-finalize` property in the template or by using the `org-capture-after-finalize-hook`, but IMO it's probably not worth it. *Why* do you want it?

Comment: I use org-capture also for meeting notes that get sorted into a datetree. In my workflow, I have a capture-buffer open as long as the meeting or the call goes. I would love to automatically store the information when it ended...

Comment: I see - I agree that it's a reasonable (if  a bit off-the-beaten-path) use case.

Comment: BTW, I should have said `:before-finalize` and `org-capture-before-finalize-hook`: those are still done in the capture buffer; the `after` versions are done in the buffer where `org-capture` was invoked, which is *not* what you want. I think that's correct but I have not checked carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, template expansion happens at the very beginning of the capture, so you cannot use `%U` or similar escapes, since you can only add the end time at the end of the capture. But there are several hooks and properties that take effect when the capture is finalized. The relevant ones here are `org-capture-before-finalize-hook` and the `:before-finalize` property of a template.

The problem is that the hook is available in virtually all versions of Org mode (certainly any version >= 9.0), but the property is only available in versions *greater* than 9.5.5. In particular, the version of Org mode in Emacs 28.2 *is* 9.5.5, so the property is *not* available there[1].

I explain how to do it in both cases, but since the property is easier to explain, I will start with that.

##### Using `:before-finalize` property

If available, the property `:before-finalize` in a capture template specifies a function (of no arguments) that is called at the end of `org-capture-finalize` just before the pre-capture window configuration and current buffer are restored (in contrast, `:after-finalize` specifies a function that is run *after* the pre-capture window configuration and current buffer are restored). So we can write the template as follows:

```el
(setq my-template '("z" "My template" entry
                     (file+headline "/path/to/foo.org" "Tasks")
                     "* TODO %?\n  %U %a"
                     :prepend t
                     :before-finalize my/capture-end-function))
```

and add it to the list of capture templates[2]:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'org-capture
  (add-to-list 'org-capture-templates my-template))
```

We still have to write a function `my/capture-end-function` to do what you want. Getting the time stamp is easy - the question is where to put it. I think that the the best place is to add it as a property, say `CAPTURE-END`, to the newly created entry:

```el
(defun my/capture-end-function ()
  (let ((ts (format-time-string "[%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M]")))
    (org-entry-put nil "CAPTURE-END" ts)))
```

This uses the current time to construct an [inactive time stamp](https://orgmode.org/manual/Timestamps.html#index-timestamp_002c-inactive)[3] and then sets the property `CAPTURE-END` to this value. The nice thing about this method is that you don't have to worry about *where* in the note the timestamp will appear: `org-entry-put` takes care of creating the `PROPERTIES` drawer (if it does  not exist) in the right place. And you can retrieve the property of the current entry later with `(org-entry-get nil "CAPTURE-END")` - see the [Property API](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-Property-API.html) section of the manual for more details.

##### Using `org-capture-before-finalize-hook`

If your version of Org mode is 9.5.5 or earlier, you will not be able to use the property method above. In that case, you can add a function to `org-capture-finalize-hook` to do the same thing. The difference is that the property is a property of a particular template, so it will only run its function for that template and for no other, whereas the hook is a blunter instrument: it will run its functions when *any* template is invoked, not just the one you want. The solution is to modify the function that you add to the hook to check *which* template it was invoked from and only act for the particular template you want; it will be a no-op in other templates.

You still have to define your template and add it to `org-capture-templates` as above. You then proceed as follows:

```el
;; for 9.5.5 and below we do it with a hook
(add-hook 'org-capture-before-finalize-hook #'my/capture-end-hook-function)

(defun my/capture-end-hook-function ()
  (when (string= (plist-get org-capture-current-plist :key) "z")
    (let ((ts (format-time-string "[%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M]")))
      (org-entry-put nil "CAPTURE-END" ts))))
```

The function is almost the same as before, except we now check that we are called from the `z` template, otherwise we do nothing.

As you can see, you need to know a bit more about the internals of the capture code to implement it (e.g. `org-capture-current-plist` is not covered in the manual - you have to read the code to discover it), but it is not complicated. Nevertheless, if the `:before-finalize` property is available to you, I think you should go with that.

---

**Footnotes**

[1] Of course, you could upgrade Org mode to a later version, but this is *not* covered in this answer.

[2] `with-eval-after-load` makes sure that we do not attempt to modify the value of the variable `org-capture-templates` before `org-capture` has been loaded and *defined* the variable in the first place.

[3] Inactive time stamps don't contribute to the agenda, so even if the file is an agenda file, you are not going to get meaningless agenda entries.

Comment: There were a couple of naming problems in the code: I think I fixed them but let me know if you run into problems.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!